# AWS lambda - best practice when reading from long list/s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, aws-lambda

I have a scheduled error handling lambda, I would like to use Serverless technology here as opposed to a spring boot service or something.

The lambda will read from an s3 bucket and process accordingly. The problem is at times the s3 bucket may have high volume of data to be processed. long running operations aren't suited to lambdas.

One solution I can think of is have the lambda read and process one item from the bucket and on success trigger another instance of the same lambda unless the bucket is empty/fully-processed. The thing i don't like is that this is synchronous and quite slow. I also need to be conscious of running too many lambdas at the same time as we are hitting a REST endpoint as part of the error flow and don't want to overload it with too many requests.

I am thinking it would be nice to have maybe 3 instances of the lambdas running at the same time  until the bucket is empty but not really sure, I am wondering if anyone has any nice patterns that could be used here or suggestions on best practices?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to _schedule_ the Lambda function? If you configure an Amazon S3 Event to trigger the Lambda function, the function will execute immediately after object creation. Lambda will automatically scale (eg run in parallel) to handle all files arriving, up to the concurrency limit (default is 1000, but can be increased). You can also set a provisioned capacity to limit the number of concurrent executions of the Lambda function.

Comment: Because we only want to process the files in the s3 bucket once another service has become available again or on a schedule to avoid unnecessarily hammering the lambda.

Comment: What do you mean by "unnecessarily hammering the lambda"? Can you tell us more about "once another service has become available again"?

Comment: there is a legacy service that is known to go down, when it does instead of sending files to it we store in s3 bucket.so it would not make sense to straight away try our lambda which will fail again because legacy service is down, it would only send the file back into the s3 bucket which would trigger the lambda again for hours accumulating costs until the legacy service is back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a S3 bucket for processing your files.

Enable a trigger S3 -> Lambda, on every new file in the bucket lambda will be invoked to process the file, every file is processed separately. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

Once the file is processed you could either delete or move file to other place.

About concurrency please have a look at provisioned concurrency https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html

**Update:**
As you still plan to use a scheduler lambda and S3

1. Lambda reads/lists only the filenames and puts messages into SQS to process the file.
2. A new Lambda to consume SQS messages and process the file.

Note: I would recommend using SQS initially if the files/messages are not so big, it has built it recovery mechanics, DLQ , delays, visibility etc which you could benefit more than the simple S3 storage, second way is just create message with file reference and still use SQS.

Comment: No this won't work as it is a scheduled lambda that will be run at a certain time of the day or possibly when we know the REST service is back up

Comment: @AnonymousAlias Then create another lambda which just moves files to the bucket for processing and it will follow this answer. Your trigger could trigger something else, it is not required to process all files with one lambda it is not recommended.

Comment: @AnonymousAlias Why don't you process files once they arrive at folder, is this scheduled trigger really required ?

Comment: You see we only want to process the files in the s3 bucket once another service has become available again or on a schedule to avoid unnecessarily hammering the lambda. So files will go to this bucket because they have failed due to another service being down, if we try straight away the service will still be down.

Comment: @AnonymousAlias Updated with a way using SQS as your buffer point before processing.

Comment: I'd suggest having Amazon S3 Events trigger immediately on new files, and have it put a message in the SQS queue. Then, the schedule can trigger "something" to process those messages later. A small app would be required to pull the messages from SQS and call the Lambda function, rather than directly connecting the Lambda function to the queue.

Comment: You are right we need to use S3 because the size of the files and there is a limit on SQS so unfortunately SQS is not an option.

Comment: @AnonymousAlias what is the limit on SQS you refer to?

Comment: @jarmod SQS supports a maximum message size of 256kb.

Comment: Why would that be a limitation for you? Would you not just be sending small messages including an S3 object key and some associated metadata to SQS?

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate the lambda that is called by the scheduler from the lambda that is doing the actual processing. When the scheduler calls the first lambda, it can look at the contents of the bucket, then spawn the worker lambdas to process the objects. This way you have control over how many objects you want per worker.

Comment: How this solution is distributive and how it scales , lambda is supposed to process a single file ?

Comment: Depends on your code. For example you can code like "a worker processes at most 10 objects". Then the scheduler lambda looks at the bucket, sees 65 objects, then spawns 7 lambdas, each getting a list of objects to process. If you want more parallelization you increase the "10", if you want less lambdas, you decrease it

Comment: I do like the sound of this approach, it might add some extra components and more complexity that i was hoping for but will keep question open for a bit and might choose to use this approach

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, I would recommend:

- Configure an Amazon S3 Event so that a message is pushed to an Amazon SQS queue when the objects are created in the S3 bucket
- Schedule an AWS Lambda function at regular intervals that will:

  - Check that the external service is working
  - Invoke a Lambda function to process one message from the queue, and keep looping

The hard part would be throttling the second Lambda function so that it doesn't try to send all request at once (which might impact that external service).

You could probably do this by using a Step Function to trigger Lambda and then, if it was successful, trigger another Lambda function. This could even be done in parallel, such as allowing up to three parallel Lambda executions. The benefit of using Step Functions is that there is no cost for "waiting" for each Lambda to finish executing.

So, the Step Function flow would be something like:

- Invoke a "check external service" Lambda function

  - If it fails, then quit the flow
- Invoke the "processing" Lambda function

  - Get one message
  - Process the message
  - If successful, remove the message from the queue
  - Return success/fail
- If it was successful, keep looping until the queue is empty

Comment: Messages are too large to be stored in a queue unfortunately

Comment: A standard practice for "large messages" is to store the data in an Amazon S3 object, and then include a reference to that data in the Amazon SQS message.